# Disable button until multiple checkboxes are checked on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I saw more than one topic like this on the internet, but non of all them were up-to-date or solved my problem. How to disable the button until multiple checkboxes are checked? I tried c1 == false && c2 == false etc. but if one of them works the other one doesn't work. Couldn't understand.

```
BlocBuilder<CheckboxCubit, CheckboxState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Checkbox( //First Checkbox
                    value: c1,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      context.read<CheckboxCubit>().changeValue(value!);
                      c1 = !c1;
                    },
                  ),
                  const Flexible(
                    child: AutoSizeText(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor',
                      maxLines: 4,
                      minFontSize: 6,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          BlocBuilder<CheckboxCubit, CheckboxState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Checkbox( //Second Checkbox
                    value: c2,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      context.read<CheckboxCubit>().changeValue(value!);
                      c2 = !c2;
                    },
                  ),
                  const Flexible(
                    child: AutoSizeText(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor',
                      maxLines: 4,
                      minFontSize: 6,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.h, bottom: 20.h),
            child: ButtonWidget( //Button
              text: 'Save',
              onPressed: () {
                
                context.read<CityCubit>().sendUserInfo(
                      userId: signCubit.state.signUpResponse?.data!.userId.toString() ?? '0',
                     ....
                    );
              },
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              width: 274.w,
              height: 30.h,
            ),
```

Comment: what do you mean by this: `but if one of them works the other one doesn't work`?  could you show us what you have tried in question's code?

Comment: It works when c1 is true but shouldn't work because c2 is still false.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with bloc before, but perhaps you can store the checkbox values in a list and then check if that list is greater than 1.

to disable the button you must provide null to onPressed as follow:

```
onPressed: list.length < 2 ? null : () {
 doSomething();
},
```